# for loop in jinja2

Tags: ansible, template

Please explain to me how can I fix this problem?
i have this file `defaults/main.yml`

```
---
node1:
 ip: 1.1.1.1

node2:
 ip: 2.2.2.2

node3:
 ip: 3.3.3.3
```

Now, I want in template file `ip.j2` by `for loop` access the IPs of each server and save in `address` `variable`

Like this:

`address= 1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3`

I tried this code:

```
address={% for x in {{nubmer_nodes}} %}
{{node[x].ip}}
{% if loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But an error occurs. How should I do this?

**Error** :

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************

ok: [db2]
ok: [db3]
ok: [db1]

TASK [ssh : -- my loop --] *************************************************************************

fatal: [db1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: \r\naddress={% for x in {{number_nodes}} %}\r\n{{node[x].ip}}\r\n{% if loop.last %},{% endif %}\r\n{% endfor %}"}
fatal: [db2]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: \r\naddress={% for x in {{number_nodes}} %}\r\n{{node[x].ip}}\r\n{% if loop.last %},{% endif %}\r\n{% endfor %}"}
fatal: [db3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: \r\naddress={% for x in {{number_nodes}} %}\r\n{{node[x].ip}}\r\n{% if loop.last %},{% endif %}\r\n{% endfor %}"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/playbooks/get_ip_ssh.retry

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************

db1                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
db2                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
db3                        : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

**Edite-1**

I changed the `template` and `default/main.yml`code. I have names(nodes) but I can not access IPs yet.
`default/main.yml`:

```
nodes:
 node1:
     ip: 1.1.1.1

 node2:
     ip: 2.2.2.2

 node3:
     ip: 3.3.3.3
```

`get-ip.j2`

```
address={% for host in nodes %}{{host}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Output is:

```
address=node1,node3,node2
```

I also used this code:

```
address={% for host in nodes %}{{host.ip}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

OR

```
address={% for host in nodes %}{{host.[ip]}}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

But not work yet!!

**Update**

My problem solved, I use this code:

```
address={% for host in nodes %}{{ nodes[host].ip }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Answer (score 2):

A few things.

Firstly, assuming `number_nodes` has the values of 1,2,3, you are trying to access the element of `node` but you do not have such a variable in the provided yaml.

Secondly, you cannot iterate over three different variables in such a way.

However, if your yaml file looked like that:

```
---
nodes:
  - ip: 1.1.1.1
  - ip: 2.2.2.2
  - ip: 3.3.3.3
```

Your code could look like that:

```
address={% for x in {{ nodes }} %}
{{ x.ip }}
{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What is different from your code is:

- In the first line we loop over the elements of `nodes`.
- In the second you select the `ip` element of `x`, which is the each element in the loop.
- In the third line, assuming you want commas in between all elements except after the last one, you need a `not`.